# MySQL Group_Concat Repeating Values

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am working on an open source project called [PHP-Bouncer](http://code.google.com/p/php-bouncer/), and I'm having issues with a MySQL Query I am writing for it. Basically we have three tables: BouncerRoles, PageInRole, and BouncerPageOverrides. BouncerRoles contains access levels, and the other two tables link back to BouncerRoles via Foreign Key and provide multiple entries of additional data. I have written the following query to attempt to pull all of the role data I need all at once:

```
select BouncerRoles.RoleID, BouncerRoles.RoleName, 
GROUP_CONCAT(PageInRole.PageName separator '|') as ProvidedPages, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(BouncerPageOverrides.OverriddenPage,'&',BouncerPageOverrides.OverridingPage) separator '|') as OverriddenPages 
from BouncerRoles join PageInRole on BouncerRoles.RoleID = PageInRole.RoleID 
join BouncerPageOverrides on BouncerRoles.RoleID = BouncerPageOverrides.RoleID
group by BouncerRoles.RoleID;
```

The Goal of this query is to provide the RoleID, RoleName, a pipe delimited list of provided pages, and a pipe delimited list of overrides (in the form of overriddenpage&overridingpage). Everything works except the last column of the query, which repeats the entries it finds over and over like this (output in CSV format):

```
RoleID,RoleName,ProvidedPages,OverriddenPages
2,Exchange,exchange-how.php|exchange-support.php|exchange.php|premium-promo.php|exchange-resorts.php|premiumplus-promo.php|exchange-deposit.php|exchange-requestdestination.php,whyexchange.php&exhange.php|whyexchange.php&exhange.php|whyexchange.php&exhange.php|whyexchange.php&exhange.php|whyexchange.php&exhange.php|whyexchange.php&exhange.php|whyexchange.php&exhange.php|whyexchange.php&exhange.php
3,Premium,premiumplus-promo.php|premium-cruises.php|premium-resorts.php|premium-condohome.php|premium-hotelaircar.php|premium.php|premium-restaurants.php|premium-overview.php,premium-promo.php&premium.php|premium-promo.php&premium.php|premium-promo.php&premium.php|premium-promo.php&premium.php|premium-promo.php&premium.php|premium-promo.php&premium.php|premium-promo.php&premium.php|premium-promo.php&premium.php
4,"Premium Plus",premiumplus-exclusiveescapes.php|premiumplus.php|premiumplus-overview.php|premiumplus-concierge.php|premiumplus-airportlounge.php,premiumplus-promo.php&premiumplus.php|premiumplus-promo.php&premiumplus.php|premiumplus-promo.php&premiumplus.php|premiumplus-promo.php&premiumplus.php|premiumplus-promo.php&premiumplus.php
```

Is there something I've done wrong in my query to cause this?

Comment: Mind that `GROUP_CONCAT` can be a pain in the arse if you have a big result -> it will only return a limited size result (I think 1024 bytes, but am not sure), so if your resultset is bigger it will get cut off.

Comment: Are you missing a `DISTINCT` inside your `GROUP_CONCAT`? It seems like your join is returning multiple rows.

Comment: @nanne: That limit (1024) depends on a setting. It can be lengthened.

Comment: True, but you still need to be aware if it existing :). Also, but that's just my opinion, it might be tricky to ask your users to change their settings....

Comment: I previously did yet received no answers :( http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40266/how-can-i-join-one-to-one-to-many-to-one-without-using-group-concat

Comment: @ypercube how to change settings to extend the limit in android sqlite?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are probably joining a table with two tables on 1..n relationships, producing duplicate results.

- Use either `GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ...)` or
- Use two subqueries: in each one use `GROUP_CONCAT()` with group by on each of the 2 tables. Then join the two subqueries and the main table.

Comment: Adding Distinct to the second group_concat did the trick... Thanks!

Comment: Is there no other option? As with a large dataset (in my case) the subqueries are extremely slow yet I cannot use distinct as i need each value returned even if it is the same..

Comment: @ThomasClowes You can post a question then. Don't forget to include the actual query, the tables' definitions (including indexes) and the execution plan. You could also post the question at [http://dba.stackexchange.com/](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) where it may get better attention.

Comment: I previously did but no-one could help :( http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40266/how-can-i-join-one-to-one-to-many-to-one-without-using-group-concat

Comment: @ThomasClowes I don't see a query there. It's hard to understand what exactly you want. Acn you add it?