# Duplicate values in GROUP_CONCAT when using two many-to-many

Tags: sql, sqlite, many-to-many

I'm trying to get in a string two many-to-many associations. In this example, each team has an undetermined number of colours and an undetermined number won awards.

This is the schema:

[image]

And this is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT
    teams.name AS name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(colours.name) AS colours,
    GROUP_CONCAT(awards.name) AS awards
FROM
    teams

-- join colours
INNER JOIN teams_to_colours
        ON teams.id = teams_to_colours.team_id

INNER JOIN colours
        ON teams_to_colours.colour_id = colours.id

-- join awards
INNER JOIN teams_to_awards
        ON teams.id = teams_to_awards.team_id

INNER JOIN awards
        ON teams_to_awards.award_id = awards.id

WHERE
    teams.name="A-Team"

GROUP BY
    teams.id
```

**The problem is that the colours and the awards get duplicated**. Let's say A-Team has red and blue as colours, and as awards TrollAward and DarwinAward... the results I get from the SQL look like this:

```
name: "A-Team"
colours: "red,blue,red,blue"
awards: "TrollAward,DarwinAward,TrollAward,DarwinAward"
```

I have tried to join only one many-to-many, and works perfectly, so I guess I'm overseeing something with the multiple joins...

Comment: See my answer here: [MySQL Group_Concat Repeating Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486266/mysql-group-concat-repeating-values/11486365#11486365)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fast and dirty answer is to add `DISTINCT` in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` functions:

```
SELECT
    teams.name AS name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colours.name) AS colours,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT awards.name) AS awards
...
```

This may not be very efficient though with big tables. The second approach is to `GROUP BY` in two subqueries (derived tables), where you get the concatenation from `awards` in one and from `colurs` in the other, and then join these derived tables.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works with the `DISTINCT`. Anyway, could you refer to any example where I can see how these derived tables work?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140288/mysql-aggregate-functions-in-query-with-two-joins-gives-unexpected-results/14140884#14140884) (where it says *"A third option ..."*)